# Adobe AEM -Hybris product price information

Tags: import, e-commerce, aem, sap-commerce-cloud

it's stated in the [adobe eCommerce tutorial](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/ecommerce/eCommerce-hybris.html#Data%20Synchronization) that :

```
Highly volatile data, such as price information, is retrieved from the commerce engine for each page request.
```

Does it mean that on each product details request adobe aem queries hybris server for price?

in product.jsp we have the following:

```
CommerceService commerceService = resource.adaptTo(CommerceService.class);
CommerceSession session = commerceService.login(slingRequest, slingResponse);
String productPrice = session.getProductPrice(baseProduct).replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]", "");
```

Is it correct that session.getProductPrice will query hybris server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, session.getProductPrice will query hybris server

But the result relies on certain circumstances.
You need to install the apropriate bundle of hybris server from AdebeAEM Package Share.